# How can I connect to a Remote SSH project from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to connect to a SSH project with VS Code and Remote SSH extension from command line?

I'm searching for a way to open a Remote SSH project in VS Code using command line. I used to open local projects in VS Code by running:

```bash
# to open new window
code /path/to/my/project

# or to reuse some window
code -r /path/to/my/project
```

I have [Remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) and [Project Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.project-manager) extensions installed and I have a lot of projects configured in my `projects.json` and `~/.ssh/config` e.g.:

###### `~/.ssh/config`

```bash
Host project-ssh-alias
  HostName 0.1.2.3  # A valid IP of course
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-key
  User remote-user
```

###### `~/.config/Code/User/projects.json`

```json
{
  "name": "My Remote Project",
  "rootPath": "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+project-ssh-alias/path/to/my/remote-project",
  "paths": [],
  "tags": [],
  "enabled": true
}
```

**The question**: Is it possible to connect to a Remote SSH project in VS Code from command line? I've tried something like the command below, but it didn't work:

```bash
code vscode-remote://ssh-remote+project-ssh-alias/path/to/my/remote-project
```

I expect to VS Code open and connect to my SSH project using Remote SSH extension from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
code --remote ssh-remote+remote_server /code/my_project
```

Quoting from [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal) <sup><sub>([which got added in response to this answer post!](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3324#issuecomment-1440867068))</sub></sup>:

> We need to do some guessing on whether the input path is a file or a folder. If it has a file extension, it is considered a file.
>
> To force that a folder is opened, add slash to the path or use:
>
> ```
> code --folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+remote_server/code/folder.with.dot
> ```
>
> To force that a file is opened, add --goto or use:
>
> ```
> code --file-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+remote_server/code/fileWithoutExtension
> ```

You might need to quote the paths for your shell if the paths have spaces in them.

Related GitHub issue tickets:

- [Open VSCode SSH session from terminal #3738](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3738)
- [Provide a command to open a VSCode Remote SSH connection from the command line via an already open SSH connection
  #3324](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3324)

For your reference, I found this by googling "`github vscode issues commandline connect to remote ssh`"